# frequent Ajax call do not update jsp page

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts-1

i m calling ajax function on checkbox click event.

it works properly but when i check tick box speedly it will not call ajax function properly.

Please Suggest..

jQuery ajax call

```
function tickComparator(prlCode,pgGrp)
 {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: path+"resultInfo.do?method=comparator&detailPage=false&pgGrp="+pgGrp+"&pssrPrlCode="+prlCode+"&showComparator=true&cntTick="+cntTick+"&x=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
        noCache:true,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        jQuery("#compare-panel").html(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {}
        });
        }
        });
 }

<a onclick="tickComparator(<bean:write name="results2" property="pssrPrlCode"/>,'<bean:write name="results2" property="pgGrp"/>')"/>

<div id="compare-panel">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what your function is actually doing.

Comment: Please post your bind event code in jsp.

Comment: How about disabling the checkbox till the the ajax call completes. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Also give an alert or log the error message from the ajax calls. Else you wont be able to understand if there was an error.